# How can we separate logs in Appium for each test script?

Tags: selenium, appium

I have written a script where I'm calling all the necessary test cases. Appium is generating its own logs, which I can store in a text file.

But the problem is that the logs for all the scripts are in one log file and I want to separate it for each individual script.

Is that possible in Appium? f you how to I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Dinesh - I think this will not be a good practice.
**Do we really need separate log file?**

**Why we generate log file?**

- We should able to track and analyze activity created by automation.
- If needed some times that followed path give more detail information.

*This goal can be achieved by single log file.*